# Can I change a size and style in a font viewer with Combobox?

Tags: c#, user-interface

#Hello guys, I have this problem with Forms in C#, I want to make a font viewer, actually I want to
make two Combobox that make change the "graphics" and display the same name of the font in its style
and in a specific size of the second Combobox. The main problem is that the style and the size don't
change. Any error could be cool for me to be told :) Here is my code.#

```
namespace CodeImage35
{
    class Visualizer : Form
    {
        Label choose; 
        PictureBox picbox; //this is for the text 
        Graphics textm; //the text in PictureBox
        ComboBox fontsm; //font of the text
        ComboBox size; //size of the font
        String fonts; //I used this for get the fonts,maybe never is used


        public Visualizer() //Here is the UI
        {
            this.Width = 600;
            this.Height = 300;
            this.Text = "Visualizer of fonts";

            choose = new Label();
            choose.Size = new Size(100, 20);
            choose.Location = new Point(20, 20);
            choose.Text = "Choose Font:";

            picbox = new PictureBox();
            picbox.Size = new Size(300, 200);
            picbox.Location = new Point(100,150);

            

            fontsm = new ComboBox();
            fontsm.Location = new Point(110, 20);
            fontsm.Size = new Size(350, 20);

            size = new ComboBox();
            size.Location = new Point(480, 20);
            size.Size = new Size(100, 20);

            System.Drawing.Text.InstalledFontCollection fonts = new InstalledFontCollection(); //this         
            //is for the fonts
            

            foreach ( FontFamily style in fonts.Families )//I add them in the combobox here
            {
                fontsm.Items.Add(style.Name);
            }
          

            for( int s = 1; s <= 50; size++ )
            {
                size.Items.Add(s); //I add here the sizes from 1 to 50
            }


            picbox.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(write_in_PictureBox);
            Controls.Add(fontsm);
            Controls.Add(choose);
            Controls.Add(size);
            Controls.Add(picbox);

        }
        void write_in_PictureBox(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            
            String text2 = fontsm.Text;
            textm = e.Graphics;
            int x = 0;
            Int32.TryParse(size.Text, out x); //I tried with this function to make string to int for 
                                              //the parameter of "DrawString
            textm.DrawString( text2 , new Font( text2, x ), Brushes.Black, new Point(10, 10) );
        }

    }

    static class MainClass
    {   
        static void Main()
        {
            Visualizer screen1 = new Visualizer(); 
            Application.Run(screen1);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To begin fix this compiler error:

```
for( int s = 1; s <= 50; size++ )
{
    size.Items.Add(s); //I add here the sizes from 1 to 50
}
```

the correct variable to increment is **s** . Also you cold avoid to start from 1, a value really too small to render a font and appreciate the result. Starting from 6 or 8 should be fine. Apart from that...

In order to draw a string, based on the input of the two combobox, you have to handle the *SelectedValueChanged* event (or SelectedIndexChanged). Those events happen when the user change (select) a value in the combobox.

Instead, the PaintEventHandler happens when a control is being painted. See [Paint event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.paint?view=netcore-3.1).

Following your example you can attach the SelectedValueChanged event to a method that draws the string like you did in *write_in_PictureBox* method .

```
//put this at the end of the constructor method.
//The event will be triggered on both combobox, allowing the user to see the result of it's selection whatever combobox is edited
fontsm.SelectedValueChanged += (sender, args) => DrawFont();
size.SelectedValueChanged += (sender, args) => DrawFont();

//that's just a method to handle the event
private void DrawFont()
{
    using (var g = picbox.CreateGraphics()) //remember to always dispose a disposable resource
    {
        //clear the area before draw the new string
        g.Clear(DefaultBackColor);
        if (!Int32.TryParse(size.Text, out int x)) x = 12; //if no value is selected for size combobox, use 12 as default
        string text = fontsm.Text;
        g.DrawString(text, new Font(text, x), Brushes.Black, new Point(10, 10)); 
    }
}
```

By the way... if you just want to show a font preview... it would be much easier for you to just put a label and change it's text and font property :) .